# radosgw remain shadow files when I delete objects in pool

Tags: ceph, radosgw

I deployed the rgw in my cluster and when I did the test,I frequently uploaded and deleted the objects,and after that I found a lot of shadows files remain in .rgw.buckets,I try to run the commend:radosgw-admin temp remove but it give me a error which arg remove cannot be recognized.I also try to config gc but gc list always gives me en empty list.
Could someone tell how to deal with shadow file or how to delete them?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

the gc triggers after sometime, but it does take a few hours before it can get all the shadow objects... What does gc list --include-all show? In general, --include-all may show the objects pending deletion) Does it decrease after a few hours?

Another option is to try finding orphaned objects using radosgw-admin orphans find on the pool, these can be deleted later manually via a rados client of choice (edit not sure why my previous answer got deleted..)